# Is there a way to get the previous page URL to the current referring page?

Tags: redirect

Is there a way to get the previous page URL to the current referring page?

(I mean the referring page to the referring page.)

Or is this only accessible via the browser history?

Answer (score 3):

You can get the previous page (within the same site) with `{{ craft.app.request.referrer }}`.

Comment: I need to access the page URL before that though.